# Understanding Distributional Meanings and Test Functions for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

My question is about distributional meanings in PDEs. My specific question is at the bottom, but I'd be interested in a bit of general theory (even if this is a link to a particularly good set of notes). In my lectures, not much is said about them and I don't exactly understand what's going on!

[image: Picture]

(I believe that $|x|^{-1}$ is $\| x \|^{-1}$, not $|x_1|^{-1}$; this makes sense in the latter part of the question.)

I think that, given $T \in \mathcal S'(\Bbb R^3)$ and letting $f:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ via $f(x) = \| x \|^{-1}$, we obtain
$$-T(\Delta f) = 4 \pi \delta_0 \ \iff T({2 \over {\|x\|^3}}(3\|x\| + 4) = 4 \pi \delta_0,$$
by taking the Laplacian $\Delta$ of $f$. Is this correct?

If it is, then I still don't know how to do the next bit. By taking the divergence of $R_\epsilon := B_R \setminus B_\epsilon$, we should get $0$ on the LHS for all $\epsilon > 0$, but then $4\pi$ in the limit; how do I take the divergence with the $T$ there? Do I use the integral notation and then try using one of Green's identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In various branches of mathematics it turns out to be profitable to shift attention from what some objects **are** to what they **do**. In case of functions, we shift attention from (locally integrable) functions  $f$ being some set of ordered pairs, etc to what it does: it defines a linear functional on the set of test functions, by
$$\varphi \mapsto \int f\varphi \tag1$$
When a derivative $f'$ exists, it also acts on test functions: 
$$\varphi \mapsto \int f'\varphi = -\int f\varphi' \tag2$$
Then we realize that the right hand side in (2) makes sense for any $f$, even discontinuous or nondifferentiable ones. So, even though we may not have a concrete picture of what $f'$ is in such cases, we can still say what it does to test functions.

Standard example is $f$ being the Heaviside function. For any test function $\varphi$ we have 
$$-\int f\varphi' = -\int_0^\infty \varphi' = \varphi(0)$$
This is written simply as $f'=\delta_0$, with $\delta_0$ being the name of the linear functional $\varphi\mapsto \varphi(0)$.

Similarly for the Laplacian: $\Delta f$ acts on test functions by $\varphi \mapsto \int f\Delta \varphi$. Another way to write this down: $\Delta f=T$ where $T$ is the distribution defined by $T(\varphi)=\int f\Delta \varphi$.

When you write $T(\Delta f) $, this is already a confusion. We don't plug $\Delta f$ into distributions,   $\Delta f$ **is** a distribution, into which we plug test functions.

I don't understand where ${2 \over {\|x\|^3}}(3\|x\| + 4)$ came. Must be a computational mistake. The function $|x|^{-1}$ (yes, $|\cdot|$ means Euclidean norm; you can write it as $\|\cdot\|$ if you want) has zero Laplacian for $x\ne 0$, in the classical sense.

The calculation of $\Delta(|x|^{-1})$, following the hint in your question, is [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/318365/) (the answer talks about measures, but you can read it substituting "distribution" for measure")

As for a reference,  Folland's *Real Analysis* has a chapter on distributions.

Comment: Thank you very much; that is truly excellent! I must have just made a computational slip in determining the Laplacian of $\| x\|^{-1}$; I should have remembered that $f(x) = r^n$ $(r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$) has zero Laplacian for $n=-1$ (and possibly other $n$...).

Comment: Your explanation is much clearer than my lecture notes, particularly the bit about $\delta_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I'm still really stuck when I try it tomorrow, is it ok if I post another comment and you can help? (Wouldn't need to be such a long response!)

Comment: @SmileySam No problem.